# Looking for IPTABLES and UFW readily available, the best proven rules

Tags: iptables, ufw

ok i am up with UBUNTU finally, and liked the distro!
particularly ufw, synaptic and software manager.

as i am pretty blind newbie to linux, i need some help securing Ubuntu desktop. I've gone through documentation but barely understand any, went all over my head!!!

**can any Ubuntu pro show or post ready available best proven rules for IPTABLES and UFW fo avoid various types of hacks and net-attacks?**

thanks in advance 
LUBU

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, assuming you are using a desktop, the rules for ufw are sufficient (if not overkill). The rules are reviewed by the Ubuntu Security team.

```
sudo ufw enable
```

If you want a graphical front end, use gufw

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

Then search your menu for firewall.

[image: gufw]

Other then that , there is no single set of fool proof rules that applies for all users all the time. If the above command is insufficient we would need to know why they are insufficient in order to give better advice.

See also

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Policies#No_Open_Ports